# How to group by with a condition

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle11g

I have the following table and data below. For simplicity sake I have made `shape` a `varchar`. Grouping by `shape` column is **NOT** an option. Shape can only be selected or joined on `id`.

If I use the select statement below, it is exactly the result I want. it is just missing the `id` column:

```
SELECT badge_id, likes
FROM table1 t1
GROUP BY badge_id, likes;
```

My question is, if the `badge_id` and `likes` combination are the same as another row, I want to show the first instance of `id`. If the `badge_id` and `likes` combination aren't the same as another row, then show me all its unique `id`'s.

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    
    id          NUMBER,

    badge_id    varchar(100) NOT NULL,

    likes       varchar(100) NOT NULL,

    shape        varchar(100) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

INSERT INTO table1 (id, badge_id, likes, shape) VALUES
(1, 'B001', 'red, blue', 'Rectangle');
INSERT INTO table1 (id, badge_id, likes, shape) VALUES
(2, 'B001', 'red, blue', 'Rectangle');
INSERT INTO table1 (id, badge_id, likes, shape) VALUES
(3, 'B003', 'green, red', 'Triangle');
INSERT INTO table1 (id, badge_id, likes, shape) VALUES
(4, 'B003', 'purple, red', 'Square');
INSERT INTO table1 (id, badge_id, likes, shape) VALUES
(5, 'B555', 'blue, black', 'Circle');
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/83e12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use an analytic function.  Something like [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/83e12/8)

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
        SELECT t1.*, 
               row_number() over (partition by badge_id, likes
                                      order by id) rn
          FROM table1 t1
       ) subQ
 WHERE subQ.rn = 1
```

The `partition by` says that we want each distinct set of `badge_id, likes` to have its own set of row numbers.  `order by id` says that the row numbers should follow the `id` order.  So the lowest `id` for any combination of `badge_id, likes` will have a row number of 1 assigned.  And that's what we filter out in the `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

I THINK all you want is DISTINCT

```
select distinct
      badge_id,
      likes, 
      shape 
   from 
      table1 
   order by
      badge_id,
      likes
```

by doing DISTINCT, only one record is returned for badge 8001 (where it has same valules for badge and likes, but also gives you the only shape it has along for the ride.

For your badge 8003, you would see both entries just by the nature of distinct (red,blue) vs (green, red).

Badge 8555 only has one entry so that would just come directly.

Now, a different scenario you did NOT cover.  A condition with same badge and like, but the SHAPE was different.  In the query above, it WOULD show each one individually such as

```
id    badge    likes      shape
 6    8765     blue, red  Triangle
 7    8765     blue, red  Square
 8    8765     blue, red  Circle
 9    8765     blue, red  Triangle
10    8765     blue, red  Circle
```

So what would/should this one show... By using distinct, all 3 combinations would show. since IDs 8 and 10 are the same, it would only show 1... same with IDs 6 and 9

Comment: So your example, while it works, I need the `id`. I only need to check if the `badge_id` and `likes` combination are the same as another row. I don't really need the `badge_id` or `likes` or `shape`, column but I need the `id`. This is because if I have the ID, I can left join the unique results from this select statement with `table1` again to obtain the badge, likes and shape column

Comment: All of this effort is because `shape` is actually a `SDO_GEOMETRY` column, but I can't do anything with it because it takes the database too long to deal with `SDO_GEOMETRY` datatypes. That is why for simplicity I used `varchar` data type for `shape`. I've also updated my question. Hopefully it makes more sense